# Label and paragraph on the same row, bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I usually do like this if I want to objects on the same row:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <label>Name:</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>John</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The other way I know is to use row and columns. Alot of code for a simple thing. Is there something built in for this?

Something like:

```
<div class="some-neat-bootstrap-class">
 <label>Name:</label>
 <p>John</p>
</div>
```

Can't find any in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display both of those elements inline.

```
.some-neat-bootstrap-class label,
some-neat-bootstrap-class p {
    display:inline;
}
```